# toString Method ArrayList simple recursion

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, tostring

I am trying to print the contents of a list recursively and this is what I should be getting

```
[6, 8] but I am getting [8, 8 6, 6]
```

But it's printing in the wrong order and it's also duplicating itself.

I'm still very new to recursion so I apologize if it sounds like a basic question. This is my method:

```
private String toStringHelper (ArrayList<E> elements, int index, String ret){

  if(index>=elements.size())return ret;

  if (ret != null){ret +=  elements.get(index).toString() + ", ";}  
  ret += elements.get(index).toString() + " "; 

  return toStringHelper(elements, ++index, ret); 
}
```

How would I structurally fix it so it outputs the way I want it to? Does my recursion print it in a reverse order?

Comment: please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I added more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  private String toStringHelper(ArrayList<E> elements, int index) {

    if (index >= elements.size())
      return "";
    String s = toStringHelper(elements, index + 1);
    if (index < elements.size() - 1)
      s += ", ";
    s += elements.get(index).toString();
    return s;
  }
```

Hope its work !

Answer (score 3):

You miss the else i think:

```
    if (ret == null) {
        ret = elements.get(index).toString() + ", ";
    } else {
        ret += elements.get(index).toString() + " ";
    }
```

Comment: that still prints [8, 6, ]

Comment: Have changed my anser. Output is `6, 8`

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to **avoid** using that `ret` argument; that just complicates matters. Why not go for something like:

```
private String toStringHelper (ArrayList<E> elements, int index) {
  if(index>=elements.size()) {
    return ""; 
  }
  String trailingElements = toStringHelper(elements, ++index);
  if (trailingElements.isEmpty()) {
    return elements.get(index).toString();
  else {
    return elements.get(index).toString() + ", " + trailingElements;
  }
```

}

For example.

And just for the record: of course it is possible to use *recursion* here; but this is one of the examples where a simply for-each loop should be used; as it is much easier to read; and does the job in a straight forward way. In this case, that recursive method gives you *nothing* but *additional* complexity.